# What's the best way to implement a variadic template with both left and right fold

Tags: c++, variadic

I'm trying to implement something of the form

```
template<typename ...args>
void func(int l, args... arg, int r){

}
```

I could use

```
template<typename ...args>
void func(int l, int r, args... arg){

}
```

but it would make it far more unintuitive to use.
The function itself is

```
    template<typename ...TA, enable_if_t<sizeof...(TA) == 2 * (d - 1), int> = 0>
    void upd(int u1, TA... args, T val){
        u1 += n;
        while(u1){
            t[u1].upd(args..., val);
            u1 >>= 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: how about `void func(int l,std::tuple<args....> arg,int r)` ?

Comment: Please show what should be inside of `func`.

Comment: Would that require me to explicitly give the middle argument as a tuple?

Comment: From where `d` is given?

Answer (score 1):

`d` seems fixed, so it is not really variadic.

You can then have specializations (up to a certain limit)

```cpp
template <std::size_t d>
struct S;

template <>
struct S<0>
{
    void upd(int u1, T val){
        u1 += n;
        while(u1){
            t[u1].upd(val);
            u1 >>= 1;
        }
    }
};

template <>
struct S<1>
{
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    void upd(int u1, T1 t1, T2 t2, T val){
        u1 += n;
        while(u1){
            t[u1].upd(T1, t2, val);
            u1 >>= 1;
        }
    }
};

//...
// struct S<2>
// ...
// void upd(int u1, T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3, T4 t4, T val){
// ...
```

If the types T1, TN are fixed (assuming `SomeType`), one possibility is to use [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) instead of `d`

```cpp
template <std::size_t, typename T>
using always_t = T;

template <typename Seq>
struct S_impl;

template <std::size_t... Is>
struct S_impl<std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    void upd(int u1, always_t<Is, SomeType>... args, T val){
        u1 += n;
        while(u1) {
            t[u1].upd(args..., val);
            u1 >>= 1;
        }
    }
};

template <std::size_t d>
using S = S_impl<std::make_index_sequence<d>>;
```

Else, you can use tuple or reordering argument for implementation, and provide wrapper for the interface:

```
template<std::size_t... Is, typename Tuple>
auto extract(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple t)
{
    return std::tie(std::get<Is>(t)...);
}

template <typename ...Ts, enable_if_t<sizeof...(Ts) == 2 * (d - 1), int> = 0>
void upd_impl(int u1, std::tuple<Ts...> tup, T val) {
    u1 += n;
    while(u1){
        std::apply([&](auto&&... args){
            t[u1].upd(args..., val);
            u1 >>= 1;
        }, tup
    }
}

template <typename ...Ts, enable_if_t<sizeof...(Ts) == 1 + 2 * (d - 1), int> = 0>
void upd(int u1, Ts... args) {
    upd_impl(u1,
             extract(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) - 1>(),
                     std::tie(args...)),
             std::get<sizeof...(Ts) - 1>(std::tie(args...)));
}
```